# How to get the EIP value right before WinDBG attach operation?

Tags: windbg

When WinDBG attach to a process, the EIP will point at `ntdll!DbgBreakPoint` in a dedicated thread different to the main process threads.

Is it possible to get the EIP value right before the attach operation? If possible, how to get the EIP value right before the attachment happened?

Answer (score 3):

There can be `arbitrary number of threads` running in a process at any given time
you require the eip of which thread or rather could you explain what you are after   because as posted your query doesnt semm to be logical.

If you want to know where each of the thread is when you broke on attach

Find the number of threads running in the process with

```
 ~*
```

thats a `tilde and asterisk` it will list all the threads that are running at the time when windbg broke

now use the `number as a variable` in a `.for loop` to print out the `eip and ebp+4` (return address on stack)

script

```
0:019> .for (r $t0 = 0; @$t0 < 19; r $t0 = @$t0+1 ) { ~[@$t0]s; .printf "%p\t%y\t%y\n",@eip,@eip,poi(@ebp+4);   }
```

result (attached to a blank ieexplorer)

```
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    USER32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (7e4195f9)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    ADVAPI32!WmipEventPump+0x230 (77df8631)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (7c80b729)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (7c80b729)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (7c80b729)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    RPCRT4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd (77e76caf)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18 (7c80a115)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    USER32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (7e4195f9)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18 (7c80a115)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    USER32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (7e4195f9)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    RPCRT4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd (77e76caf)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!Sleep+0xf (7c802455)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    ole32!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x5c (774fe419)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    ole32!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x5c (774fe419)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (7c80b729)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (7c80b729)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    RPCRT4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd (77e76caf)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    RPCRT4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd (77e76caf)
7c90e514    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (7c90e514)    KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (7c80b729)
7c90120e    ntdll!DbgBreakPoint (7c90120e)  00000000
```